# iov and msg_control in sendmsg and recvmsg

Tags: c, linux, sockets, recvmsg, sendmsg

What is the difference between iov.iov_base and msg.msg_control ?
I'm looking at some code examples (ipuitls open source ping)
When sending data using sendmsg the packet is set in iov.iov_base
When reading data using recvmsg the packet is read from msg->msg_control directly.

What is the relationship between struct iovec and struct msghdr ? Is there a difference when reading/sending data ?

Sorry for the silly question. I didn't find an answer so far and I'm confused.
thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ancillary data or control messages (`.msg_controllen` bytes at `.msg_control`) is data provided or verified by the kernel, whereas the normal payload (in `iovec`s) is just data received from the other endpoint, unverified and unchecked by the kernel (except for checksum, if the protocol has one).

For IP sockets (see [man 7 ip](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html)), there are several socket options that cause the kernel to provide ancillary data on received messages.  For example:

- `IP_RECVORIGDSTADDR` socket option tells the kernel to provide a `IP_ORIGDSTADDR` type ancillary message (with a `struct sockaddr_in` as data), identifying the original destination address of the datagram received
- `IP_RECVOPTS` socket option tells the kernel to provide a `IP_OPTIONS` type ancillary message containing all IP option headers (up to 40 bytes for IPv4) for incoming datagrams

Ping and traceroute uses ICMP messages over IP; see [man 7 icmp](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/icmp.7.html) (and [man 7 raw](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/raw.7.html)) for details.

Because most ICMP responses do not contain useful data filled in by the sender, the `iovec`s don't usually contain anything interesting.  Instead, the interesting data is in the IP message headers and options.

For example, an [ICMP Echo reply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol#Datagram_structure) packets contain just 8 bytes (64 bits): 8-bit type (0), 8-bit code (0), 16-bit checksum, 16-bit id, and 16-bit sequence number.  To get the IP headers with the interesting fields, you need the kernel to provide them as ancillary data control messages.

---

The background:

As described in the [sendmsg()](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendmsg.2.html) and related man pages, we have

```c
ssize_t sendmsg(int sockfd, const struct msghdr *msg, int flags);

struct msghdr {
    void         *msg_name;       /* Optional address */
    socklen_t     msg_namelen;    /* Size of address */
    struct iovec *msg_iov;        /* Scatter/gather array */
    size_t        msg_iovlen;     /* # elements in msg_iov */
    void         *msg_control;    /* Ancillary data */
    size_t        msg_controllen; /* Ancillary data buffer len */
    int           msg_flags;      /* Flags (unused) */
};

struct iovec {
    void         *iov_base;       /* Starting address */
    size_t        iov_len;        /* Number of bytes to transfer */
};
```

with [man 3 cmsg](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/cmsg.3.html) describing how to construct and access such ancillary data,

```c
struct cmsghdr {
    size_t        cmsg_len;    /* Data byte count, including header
                                  (type is socklen_t in POSIX) */
    int           cmsg_level;  /* Originating protocol */
    int           cmsg_type;   /* Protocol-specific type */
    unsigned char cmsg_data[]; /* Data itself */
};

struct cmsghdr *CMSG_FIRSTHDR(struct msghdr *msgh);
struct cmsghdr *CMSG_NXTHDR(struct msghdr *msgh, struct cmsghdr *cmsg);
size_t          CMSG_ALIGN(size_t length);
size_t          CMSG_SPACE(size_t length);
size_t          CMSG_LEN(size_t length);
unsigned char  *CMSG_DATA(struct cmsghdr *cmsg);
```

These ancillary data messages are always sufficiently aligned for the current architecture (so that the data items can be directly accessed), so to construct a proper ancillary message (SCM_CREDENTIALS to pass user, group, and process ID information over an Unix domain socket, or SCM_RIGHTS to pass file descriptors), these macros have to be used.  The [man 3 cmsg](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/cmsg.3.html) man page contains example code for these.

Suffice it to say, that to loop over each ancillary data part in a given message (`struct msghdr msg`), you use something that boils down to

```c
char *const  end = (char *)msg.msg_control + msg.msg_controllen;
char        *ptr = (char *)msg.msg_control;

for (char *ptr = (char *)msg.msg_control;  ptr < end;
           ptr += ((struct cmsghdr *)ptr)->cmsg_len) {
    struct cmsghdr *const cmsg = (struct cmsghdr *)ptr;

    /* level is cmsg->cmsg_level and type is cmsg->cmsg_type, and
       cmsg->cmsg_data is sufficiently aligned for the level and type,
       so you can use ((datatype *)(cmsg->cmsg_data)) to obtain a pointer
       to the type corresponding to this level and type ancillary payload.
       The exact size of the payload is
           (cmsg->cmsg_len - sizeof (struct cmsghdr))
       so e.g. an SCM_RIGHTS ancillary message, with
           cmsg->cmsg_level == SOL_SOCKET && cmsg->cmsg_type == SCM_RIGHTS
       has exactly
           (cmsg->cmsg_len - sizeof (struct cmsghrd)) / sizeof (int)
       new file descriptors as a payload.
    */
}
```